# Code snippets or code library for easy re-use in other projects (PBI, Spotfire, Tableau)

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, spotfire

I'm looking for advices and comparison between Power BI, Spotfire and Tableau, 3 main data viz tools, on the matter of scalability / re-use of code. I encounter a problem in Power BI (at least, for me, it is a concern) and I'd like to know if transitioning to Spotfire or Tableau would solve my problem.

I work on Power BI Desktop and publish reports to Power BI Service. I don't know at all Spofire nor Tableau.

I have a fairly comprehensive report (pbix file) that has the following specificities :

- 20 pages
- 20 tables with each of them having 10 calculated columns
- 60 measures
- connection to 10 SQL tables from a server
- that report is made to reflect progress/users/tasks/budget based on data from a specific project ("Project A")

Objective is to have the same report on another project ("Project B"). Actually, it's about 10 similar projects. Project B is using a very similar database, and there are 95% of the data structure in common between Project A and Project B. I can't mix users as well, they really need to be separate projects (user access, data confidentiality).

Right now, to the best of my knowledge, I would copy/paste the Report A.pbix, to make Report B.pbix and I would then have 2 different reports. Maintenance-wise, it is problematic to have to maintain 10 reports that are similar (but not identical).

I currently haven't found a way to build a "code library" that I would easily re-use in reports, that could make life easier to update to a specific formula or measure.

Now, questions to the community :

1. Q1 : Am I missing something in Power BI about code library or code sharing ?
2. Q2 : Would Tableau have a feature to help me create "similar dashboards" for 10 similar projects ?
3. Q3 : Would Spotfire have a feature to help me create "similar dashboards" for 10 similar projects ?

Thanks a lot for reading and looking forwards to your answers !

Answer (score -1):

I have used Spotfire extensively.  Since it has a published API, it can be automated using IronPython.

Comment: Could you give more details about Spotfire if it can answer the questions ? It is allowing code library or code sharing as asked?

Comment: The specifics are using the Spotfire SPK to deploy IronPython code to all clients. The detailed procedure is in the Spotfire documentation.   Currently the documentation is on this link https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-deploy-custom-python-modules-use-tibco-spotfirer